# Why celebrate Lag Ba'Omer on the 33rd according to the MaHaRIL?

Tags: shabbat, number, passover, calendar, lag-ba-omer

There are several different opinions about when the students of Rabbi Akiva died, and which days we mourn for them.

[Sefer HaToda'ah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41319&pgnum=238) quotes [the Maharil](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44458&st=&pgnum=53), who says that the students of Rabbi Akiva died throughout the 49 days of the Omer, but did not die on days during the "Holiday Days" of the Omer. These days are:

- The 7 days of Pesach
- 3 Days of Rosh Chodesh
- 7 Shabbatot

If you add them up, there are 17 days. If you take away 17 days from 49, you're left with 32 days during which the students died. That's why, according to the Maharil, we celebrate Lag Ba'Omer on the 33rd day, to commemorate that the students only died for 32 days, even if they may have died on Lag Ba'Omer itself.

However, there seems to be a problem with this calculation. One of the days of Shabbat would have also been one of the days of Pesach. If so, the students would have died on 33 of the days, not 32. If so, according to the Maharil, shouldn't we celebrate on the 34th day of the Omer, not the 33rd?

---

On further thought, I think I have more insight into the Maharil. The [Talmud (Yevamot 62B)](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=62b&format=pdf) says that the students of R' Akiva died between Pesach and Shavuot. It does not say that they died during Sefirat Ha'Omer *(although, according to the Maharil, this is what practically happened, since no one died the whole of Pesach)*. This is why the Maharil counts all 7 days of Pesach as days when no one died, even though it was part of the time of their dying.

This strengthens the question I have above, since one of the 7 days of Pesach must be Shabbat.

Comment: Unless the first day of Pesach was Shabbat...

Comment: One of the days of Rosh Chodesh could also be on Shabbat. I guess he assumes we don't worry about double counting.

Comment: @jake, We start from the second day of pesach counting the seven days of pesach.

Comment: @shulem, That was my point. That if the first day of Pesach was Shabbat, that the other seven shabbatot would be not included in the Pesach count. But that was before I realized that we're the eighth day of Pesach as well, in which case we anyways have a problem.

Comment: @jake: see the addition I made to the question, which I think explains why the Maharil counts all 7 days of Pesach.

Comment: @Menachem He can't be including the first day of pesach, because he subtracts the number of no tachanun days from 49 not 50

Comment: ...this title bothers me.  I understand why it's written as such, but it's annoying.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman: How would you title it?

Comment: @DoubleAA: I thought of that, then forgot about that. I think he counts from 49 and not 50 because the Sefira ends at Shavuot. He is subtracting from Shavuot, and that is the main thing. He gives us the number in Sefirah because it is convenient, but since the students didn't die the whole Pesach it **doesn't** matter that the Sefirah starts on the second day of Pesach instead of the first.

Comment: @Menachem If I had an idea, I'd have changed it.  But obviously La"G B'Omer is on the 33rd.  La"D would be the 34th.  So... "Why celebrate the stopping of dying of R' Akiva's students on Lag (33) B'Omer?" but that's wordy.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Not so obvious. Last summer we commemorated Tisha b'Av on 10 Av.

Comment: @DoubleAA my argument is that that shouldn't be called La"G... "Lag B'Omer" is metonymy for the celebration of the cessation of dying of R' Akiva's students, but only because we agree that it's (generally) on the La"G day of the omer.

Comment: @DoubleAA so we generally be celebrated it on the 34th of the omer, we would call it Lad B'Omer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the footnote to [this artice](http://ph.yhb.org.il/05-03-02/), the calculation of dates where death did not happen includes Isru Chag (the day after Pesach). This brings the total of "non-death days" back to 17, and solves our "off by one" problem.

---

The [Nachlat Tzvi on Orach Chaim 493](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45975&st=&pgnum=440) gives this as an answer to our question on the Maharil. Note that he explicitly dismisses the suggestion that we should count 8 days of Pesach, since the students of Rabbi Akiva lived in Israel, where they only observed 7 days.

Comment: Thanks to @Yishai for the source, posted in this answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/58972/603

Comment: @Ploni  perhaps it was self evident to him.

Answer (score 4):

The maharil  starts off saying days when no tachnun is said. [The Mishna Berurah in Biur Halacha (493:3)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14165&pgnum=197) also quotes this reason. But counts  seven days of pesach although they were in Israel and only started on the second day when we say the omer. And only six shabosos. Three days of rosh chodesh which adds up to 16 which leaves 33 days. Most likely there is a mistake in the maharil.

[The bach](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14268&pgnum=330) really asks your question and gives the above answer although not mentioning the maharil. But the [kaf hachaim (493:24](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14423&pgnum=321)) brings the bach and says he is referring to the maharil. It appears from the kaf hachaim that he  means there is a mistake in the maharil.

If so, why do we celebrate on the 33rd, of the Omer, and not the 34th? Because of the principle that, when it comes certain things (such as certain aspects of mourning), part of the day is like the whole day. (according to this answer, the mourning is only over after daybreak of the 33rd day of the Omer, not the night before).

Comment: But counts seven days of pesach although they were in Israel and only started on the second day when we say the omer. Why not six days since they only keep seven days in Israel?

Comment: The Mishna Berurah is explaining why some have the custom to only mourn until Lag Ba'Omer.

Comment: It's hard to say it's a typo in the Maharil, because the Maharil says פשו להו ל"ב, נמצא דלא מתו רק ל"ב ימים, לכן כשכלו אותן ל"ב ימים שמתו עושין למחרתן שמחה לזכר. So you have to not only adjust the ב to a ג but also deal with the language of למחרתן.

Comment: The Kaf HaChaim claims that the Bach is saying the same thing as the Maharil, but as @DoubleAA pointed out, it is difficult to say that. There appears to be a Nafka Minah between the two. That being whether one has to be in mourning the night of Lag Ba'Omer. According to the Bach/MB, yes (since Lag Ba'Omer itself is still a day of mourning, but one does not have to mourn the whole day). According to the Maharil, no (since he says that Lag BaOmer is the day **after** the dying stopped).

Comment: @Double AA, you are right. But do you really expect anyone to find a better answer when apparently the kaf hachaim and bach who both saw the maharil, couldnt find one.

Comment: @shulem Yes I do.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ How many times does Tosfot reject Rashi because of a certain reason, and then 600 years later the Pnei Yehoshua gives an answer for Rashi? Don't tell me no answer is possible because the Bach gave up.