# Minhagim of Sefirah

Tags: halacha, minhag, mourning-aveilus, sefirat-ha-omer

Most people keep only part of Sefirah (the seven-week period joining Pesach and Shavuos) as a period of semimourning: either (roughly) the first 33 days or (roughly) the last 33 days. There are circumstances under which one is permitted to change his personal Sefirah practice from the one period to the other. When does the change have to be made? For example, if one kept the restrictions of the 'first' minhag but intended to keep the 'second' can he change in mid-stream and keep the 'first'?

Comment: This question would be improved if you could provide a source for changing one's minhag re: Sefirah (I've heard it myself, but I don't have the source).

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38452) links to [this article](http://rabbikaganoff.com/the-mourning-period-of-sefirah-what-are-the-guidelines-of-the-aveilus-observed-during-the-sefirah-weeks/) (or tries to; broken link there) which says "In Rav Moshe’s opinion, these different customs should be considered as one minhag, and the differences between them are variations in observing the same minhag (Igros Moshe 1:159) [...] changing from one custom to another is not considered changing one’s minhag, and it is therefore permitted." So that's one source.

Comment: Please edit those sources into your question. I think I saw some source stating that one may change their minhag midstream such as if a wedding arose and they could not change the date. Unclear, if changing was restricted to just such cases or not.

Comment: 2 factors, here - A) A community should have one minhag and the person should follow the minhag of his community. The question is what if someone moves into a community in middle of sefira and they follow a different minhag? I think you may have to change because there shouldn't be factions in the community B) One opinion says a person has to observe 33 days - however that's done. Regardless, obviously, at some point, switching won't help no matter what you do.

Comment: @user12670 I heard that this was technically very, very lenient, but that's all I know. (My community keeps both parts of Sefira and is absurdly strict about it)